# What is the correct sql for Update a row in a table?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am able to `Insert` data into `MySQL` using `C#` fine. However, it doesn't like my `Update` `sql` below. `key` is an `autoincrement` `Primary` `Key`.

This is the code i am using. **What is the correct Update sql and the corresponding C# statement to execute it?**

```
public int UpdatetData(int key, System.DateTime ts, string user)
    {
                string sql = @"update parameters (DateTime, User) 
                              values (@timestamp, @user) where Key = @key";

                try
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", ts);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                        ...
                        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    return -1;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for the `UPDATE` statement is off, as you need to specifically set each of the columns and their new values:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE parameters 
                  SET DateTime = @timestamp,
                      User = @user
                WHERE Key = @key";
```

If you need a more generic format as a point of reference, you can use the following:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE [Table]
                  SET [Column] = [Value],
                      [OtherColumn] = [OtherValue]
                WHERE [Condition]";
```

**Example**

A complete example, along with a connection (which I didn't see defined earlier) might look like this:

```
public int UpdatetData(int key, System.DateTime ts, string user)
{
     // Build parameterized query (with escaped DateTime)
     var sql = @"UPDATE parameters 
                    SET [DateTime] = @timestamp,
                        User = @user
                  WHERE Key = @key";
     try
     {
          using(var connection = new MySqlConnection("{your-connection-string}"))
          {
               connection.Open();
               using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
               {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", ts);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
          }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
          return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the C# to execute the statement?

Comment: Your existing code should be correct after the changes to the query. The parameters will be bound to the appropriate placeholders in the query and then the `ExecuteNonQuery()` will actually make the call to the database and update your values. As mentioned by [Gordon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), you may need to explicitly escape some of your column names (mainly `DateTime`) to avoid any keyword specific conflicts (i.e. use `[DateTime]` = @timestamp instead of `DateTime = @timestamp`)

Comment: I've added an example, which should be fairly complete to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thanks. It is maddening. I can't get it to work. Sql strings are ridiculous since they are not type safe.

Comment: I got it to work. I needed to use "`" not "'".   Insanity itself.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for an `UPDATE` statement is this:

```sql
Update  `Parameters`
Set     `DateTime` = @TimeStamp,
        `User` = @User
Where   `Key` = @Key
```

The only change you need to make to the C# is your `sql` variable declaration:

```cs
string sql = 
@"
    Update  `Parameters`
    Set     `DateTime` = @TimeStamp,
            `User` = @User
    Where   `Key` = @Key
";
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the C# to execute the statement?

Comment: @Ivan Added to answer

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
update parameters (DateTime, User) 
    set DateTime = @timestamp, 
        User = @user
where Key = @key;
```

Your syntax is a bit reminiscent of an `insert`.

You should be careful with your column names.  Some are keywords in SQL and might be reserved (depending on your database).  You would need to escape them, using backtick, double quotes, or square braces, depending on your database.

Comment: Ok, but what is the C# to execute the statement?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this syntax, your syntax was a mix of an insert and an update statements.

```
string sql = @"update `parameters` 
              set `DateTime` = @timestamp ,
                  `User` = @user 
              where `Key` = @key";
```

Comment: Thanks. The quoting helped.